# Android app is supported by 0 devices in play console

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I tried to make an update to my existing app, and upload to the play store, and it says the app is supported by 0 devices. So remove all the new changes and the code looks exact the same as the old version and reupload to the play store, unfortunately, I'm still getting the same "app is supported by 0 devices". I tried a different app of mine and still the same.

The following is the permissions I have for my app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />
```

I read a couple of answers from stackoverflow, and some suggest removing the permission, so I removed all the permissions and still the problem persist. Any idea? The last time I upload the app was last night and it states Supported devices: 10695    Unsupported devices:2551

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug the Google Play Console engineers are currently working to fix it, no known ETA. I just wrote to Google after experiencing this too and this is all they could tell me. (I did suggest they provide developers with a notification to let them know of the issue).

As of 20May17 issue should be fixed I'm told, try it again.

Comment: This is still an issue on the console, it is a UI bug and does not actually mean that 0 devices are supported. The correct number of supported devices will show when you perform the rollout.

Comment: Hi, After rollout the application also, it shows zero supported devices.

Comment: Is there any workarounds, for my app also it's showing same 0 supported devices :(

Answer (score 0):

```
uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="false" />
```

set required to false in your manifest